# directing OpenSSL not to free a BIO object upon setting a new BIO

Tags: c++, openssl

In this sample code:

```
BIO *bio1 = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO *bio2 = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
SSL_set_bio(ssl, bio1, bio1);
SSL_set_bio(ssl, bio2, bio2);
```

the last call to SSL_set_bio automatically calls BIO_free(bio1).
Is there anyway to tell OpenSSL not to do so?

I know that upon creating a memory bio with BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()) I can tell OpenSSL not to free it's memory buffer with BIO_set_close(bio, BIO_NOCLOSE). Is there anything similar for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to prevent `SSL_set_bio` from freeing the current BIO in the public API.  You can see in the source code that it simply checks whether each bio is not null and then frees it.

The main idea is that after you call `SSL_set_bio`, OpenSSL owns the BIO and is responsible for it.

```
void SSL_set_bio(SSL *s,BIO *rbio,BIO *wbio)
        {
        /* If the output buffering BIO is still in place, remove it
         */
        if (s->bbio != NULL)
                {
                if (s->wbio == s->bbio)
                        {
                        s->wbio=s->wbio->next_bio;
                        s->bbio->next_bio=NULL;
                        }
                }
        if ((s->rbio != NULL) && (s->rbio != rbio))
                BIO_free_all(s->rbio);
        if ((s->wbio != NULL) && (s->wbio != wbio) && (s->rbio != s->wbio))
                BIO_free_all(s->wbio);
        s->rbio=rbio;
        s->wbio=wbio;
        }
```

If I had a legitimate reason to keep the bio buffer around in production code, I would write my own bio and use that.  It's not as hard as it sounds.  Just copy `<openssl source>/crypto/bio/bss_mem.c`, rename the functions and `mem_method` table, and then replace the behavior of `mem_free()`.  Then instead of `BIO_s_mem`, pass `BIO_custom_mem_bio` or whatever you name the accessor function for your bio.

If I needed it for debugging purposes and not production code, I'd probably just grovel into the internals of the `ssl_st` struct (`SSL *`) and make all the bios NULL before calling `SSL_set_bio`.  But I wouldn't do that in production code because future SSL versions may break that code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BIO_up_ref()` to increase the reference count. 
`BIO_free()` would decrease the count, but not free it.

Comment: can you safely use this to share static global BIOs amongst all connections?